# WP API post categories are not in hierarchical order

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WP-API to develop an app while using wordpress as its CMS. My problem is when I want to show the categories hierarchy in the post.

I realise that wordpress arranged categories in alphabetical order, so this messed up the breadcrumb.

what I want:

ParentCat > ChildCat > GranchildCat

What I got instead:

ChildCat > GrandchildCat > ParentCat

How can I make WP-API to arrange the categories ID in hierarchical order? I never touch any wordpress programming, but I'll be glad if to learn it if it can solve my problem.

Thank you very much

Comment: by default wp rest api post only show category id(s) in the response. if you need to add hierarchical order you need to add custom function to be added in the fields. There are many ways to get hierarchy category in a single post.. you may check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044343/grouping-parent-and-child-categories-for-post-and-displaying/44052635#44052635